# Summation to a formula

Tags: summation, combinations

I am trying to turn a summation into a formula, and thought of Newton’s Binomial Theorem but I don't think it would be helpful in this case. I am trying to evaluate possible strings of {1, 2, 3}, and trying to evaluate number of strings that contains odd number of {3} in string of length n. Any suggestion to help practice/turn this summation into a formula? 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}{\binom{n}{2k+1} \cdot\ \mathrm{2}^{n-(2k +1)}}$$

Thank you

Comment: What kind of formula do you expect to get?

Comment: I want to produce a formula that doesn't contain summation

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake, I edited it and changed the n to 2

Comment: Again, i supposed to be k. My bad, new to this formatting

Comment: Do you consider the strings with permuted elements as distinct?

Comment: No, the summation works to evaluate strings of length n and strings contains odd number of {3}. If you input a value of n, it will provide you with a correct answer. I just want to be helped with turning this into a formula or referenced to an a lecture on how to turn summation + combination into a formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your notations, suppose that there are $P_n$ ways when the string length is $n$, to get $P_{n+1}$, this is what you can do:

Let $s_n$ be a string. Suppose there are even number of 3, you can get an odd sequence by appending a 3 after $s_n$. There are $3^n - P_n$ ways to do so.

Suppose there are odd number of 3, you can get an odd sequence by appending a 1 or a 2. There are $2P_n$ ways to do so. Therefore $P_{n+1} = P_n + 3^n$. Since $P_1 = 1$, you have

$$
P_n = 1 + 3 + \cdots + 3^{n-1} = \frac{3^n - 1}{2}.
$$

**Alternative solution:** 
$$
\begin{aligned}
(2+1)^n &= \sum_{2 \ | \ k}\binom nk 2^{n-k} + \sum_{2 \ | \ (k+1)}\binom nk 2^{n-k}\\
(2-1)^ n &= \sum_{2 \ | \ k}\binom nk 2^{n-k} - \sum_{2 \ | \ (k+1)}\binom nk 2^{n-k}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

And then subtract the two formulas and divide by 2.